# Constraints on the number of messages persisted in a channel in twilio programmable chat

Tags: chat, twilio

Is there a limit on the number of messages that will be kept persisted in a twilio channel ?
As time passes, will older messages be purged ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Messages will not be purged from your channels. They are always there for you to retrieve using the [`getMessages` method](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/0.11.1/docs/Channel.html#getMessages__anchor) in the JavaScript library and a [variety of methods in iOS](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/chat/releases/0.16.0/docs/Classes/TCHMessages.html#//api/name/messageWithIndex:completion:) and [Android](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/chat/releases/0.11.2/docs/com/twilio/chat/Messages.html#getLastMessages-int-com.twilio.chat.CallbackListener-). If a channel has a lot of messages, you will have to page through them using these methods too.

Let me know if that helps at all.